# Burger menu won't open when toggled

Tags: javascript, html, css

the burger menu I've created using plain HTML, CSS, and JS does not open when clicked and I am at a loss for what to try next. The goal is for the burger menu to show up in mobile view and use 100% of the screens width to display the navigation when toggled. Here is a codepen with my code as well.
https://codepen.io/alec-johnson/pen/dyMgKeN

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');
const navbarLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar-links');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(121, 173, 173, 0.3);
  color: rgb(87, 82, 82);
}

.brand-title {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.navbar-links {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(87, 82, 82);
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.navbar-links li a:hover {
  color: rgba(121, 173, 173);
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(87, 82, 82);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navabr-links ul li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }
  .navabr-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Griffin Murnane</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="brand-title">Griffin Murnane</div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `navbar-links active` is not defined. Don't expect it to do anything if you haven't defined it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `.navabr-links` here

> `.navabr-links.active {display: flex;}`
> so it will be
> `.active {display: flex;}`

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');
const navbarLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar-links');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(121, 173, 173, 0.3);
  color: rgb(87, 82, 82);
}

.brand-title {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.navbar-links {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(87, 82, 82);
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.navbar-links li a:hover {
  color: rgba(121, 173, 173);
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(87, 82, 82);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navabr-links ul li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }
  .active {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Griffin Murnane</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="brand-title">Griffin Murnane</div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```